# How can I enforce constraints on dates in action forms?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-actions

How do I put a constraint on a parameter of type date that I am using in my actions form? I have date1 and date2 and need to have date2 > date1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under submission criteria create a new condition for your two date parameters, in this case: date2 “is greater than” date1.
[image: Submission Criteria]
On the same tab you can also set a Failure message to guide your users, for example: “date2 needs to be after date1.”
[image: Failure Message]
While you can still pick any date in the date picker of the action form, it won’t be possible to submit the form anymore if the date2 is before or at the same time as date1.